# Python error 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, bcrypt

I have this code and I'm using python 3.7

```
def hash_password(password):
    return bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())


def credentials_valid(username, password):
    with session_scope() as s:
        user = s.query(User).filter(User.name.in_([username])).first()
        if user:
            return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), user.password.encode('utf8'))
        else:
            return False
```

But when I try to run I get this error:

```
return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), user.password.encode('utf8'))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: what is the type of password variable?

Comment: I think the error say's `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'` you can't encode byte to byte

Comment: Hi, im getting my password from a SQLite database.

Answer (score 2):

*[checkpw(password, hashed_password)](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/blob/22c89ea3891ab5926400f0d9d3af42357b5a540b/src/bcrypt/__init__.py#L97)* function of **bcrypt** takes encoded inputs.

Your two parameters, password and hashed_password, if they are in unicode, need to be encoded. This is what you did.
However, the "password" parameter that you gave to your function seems to be already encoded as the Python interpreter gave this AttributeError.

Check out this working implementation:

```
import bcrypt

password = "asd123"
hashed_password_encoded = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
hashed_password = hashed_password_encoded.decode("utf8")

is_valid = bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), hashed_password.encode('utf8'))
print(is_valid)
```

Comment: Friend, im gettin my password from SQLite database.

Comment: @AndresHernandez If you are (and should) storing your password encrypted and in unicode instead of bytes, then you will need to do `password.encode('utf8')` to convert it to bytes. Whereas, if you are storing the password in bytes, then you do not need to encode it again.